# Python Regex for matching a printf-like format string with the actual print

Tags: python, regex, printf

I have many `bla bla bla %d %c %s bla bla bla`- printf like format strings. I also have the actual prints i.e. `bla bla bla 80 @ port bla bla bla`. I want to match the print with correct format string and parse the % arguments as a list. i.e. `[80, '@', 'port']` I think regex is a good approach here. How to do it? Want a solution in python.
Advanced: Any way to parse space separated string arguments too i.e. (`"bla bla bla 80 @ port service bla bla bla"`), `[80, '@', 'port service']` ?

Comment: Escape the constant parts of the format string and replace the percent-formats with appropriate regex patterns.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: @MichaelButscher is it possible for u to give a short demo please? I am quite new to regex, now the basic regex only.

Comment: For an integer consisting of digits only the appropriate regex is `[0-9]+`. But you should better play around with regexs yourself to learn how they work.

Comment: I worked out a solution, by replacing "bla bla bla %d %c %s bla bla bla" by "bla bla bla (.*) (.*) (.*) bla bla bla", but problem arises when format string const i.e. bla bla contains *